# Safe read in Aeson parseJSON

Tags: haskell, applicative, aeson

I'm using Aeson to parse json quote data from Yahoo's API. A quote might look like this:

```
{
  "date": "2010-03-10",
  "Date": "2010-03-10",
  "Open": "0.37",
  "High": "0.37",
  "Low": "0.34",
  "Close": "0.35",
  "Volume": "443000",
  "Adj_Close": "0.35"
}
```

(that's using [this](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/?q=show%20tables&env=store://datatables.org/alltableswithkeys#h=select+%2a+from+yahoo.finance.historicaldata+where+symbol+%3D+%22ACB.AX%22+and+startDate+%3D+%222009-09-11%22+and+endDate+%3D+%222010-03-10%22) YQL query)

As you can see, the numbers are quoted. I can write a `fromJSON` implementation like this:

```
instance FromJSON Quote where
  parseJSON (Object o) =
    Quote <$> o .: "Date"
          <*> o .: "Open"
          <*> o .: "High"
          <*> o .: "Low"
          <*> o .: "Close"
          <*> o .: "Volume"
  parseJSON _ = mzero
```

which is the same as what would be derived. Unfortunately this only works if I want Open, High, Low, etc, to be a Text type. The parse fails if I try and have any of those fields as Double, say.

I can write this:

```
<*> (fmap read $ o .: "Open")
```

to get it as anything I like, but this uses `read`, which is a partial function. How would I get the above functionality without using a partial function?

Comment: What would you like to happen when read fails?

Comment: Hmm, I have been using eitherDecode from Data.Aeson, so I'd probably just like it to return a Left err, ideally with the name of the field that failed. In practice I doubt it will fail but I don't like the idea of ignoring the possibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, find a safe read function. I had to [hoogle it](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=read+%2Bsafe).

Second, you have to use more than just applicative to get choice.  In the below, I used `readMay` for the safe read and made a helper function to extract the fields while applying the Read instance.

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings, NoMonomorphismRestriction #-}
import Safe
import Data.Aeson
import Data.Aeson.Types (Parser)
import Data.Text as T
import Data.Word
import Control.Applicative
import Control.Monad

data Quote = Quote Text Double Double Double Double Word64
instance FromJSON Quote where
  parseJSON (Object o) = do
    let readField :: (Read a) => T.Text -> Parser a
        readField f = do
            v <- o .: f
            case readMay (T.unpack v) of
                Nothing -> fail $ "Bad Field: " ++ T.unpack f
                Just r  -> return r
    Quote <$> o .: "Date"
          <*> readField "Open"
          <*> readField "Close"
          <*> readField "Low"
          <*> readField "High"
          <*> readField "Volume"
  parseJSON _ = mzero
```

Comment: Thanks, I think I was getting confused because I was trying to use the applicative syntax when the power of the monadic syntax was required. Also, far as I can tell the NoMonomorphismRestriction isn't doing anything here, it still worked without that.

Comment: Actually, I think that might be possible in applicative. I might give that a try.